# How to overwrite settings from cmake modules from toolchain file?

Tags: cmake, gnu, cmake-modules

I have a CMake Toolchain file that cross compiles for arm-linux on an x86_64-linux host.
During configuration, my toolchain file is parsed and it (correcty) finds a GNU compiler. Therefore it will load `GNU.cmake` (in my case `/usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/Compiler/GNU.cmake`). The including hierarchy here is unclear to me (could not find documentation. Any link is appreceated). However it seems like this:

- root `CMakeLists.txt` to `project()`
- my toolchain.cmake
- stuff in modules dir (including `GNU.cmake`)
- loads `%_INIT` variables to `%` Cache variables
- continue after `project()`

Say i want this target to build only with -O2 optimization. I set it in my toolchain, because it is then global for many project.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT "-O2")
```

but then [GNU.cmake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/Compiler/GNU.cmake#L62) is loaded and appends it with "-O3". Therefore my setting is overwritten. After this i can only overwrite it in my projects `CMakeLists.txt` files. I would have to do this for each project, and developers will miss this!

So, my question is (repeating the headline): How to overwrite settings from CMake modules from toolchain file?

Answer (score 2):

For the reasons you pointed out you cannot do this.  Maybe this could be considered a limitation of toolchain files but it is how it currently works.

Now digging into the modules, the module that loads `GNU.cmake` is `CMakeCInformation.cmake` and `CMakeCXXInformation.cmake`.

It may be possible to override these settings by using a different file that gets loaded after `GNU.cmake` by using the variable `CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE_<lang>`.  I found this old email that talks about it:  https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-April/021337.html

It is also mentioned here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE.html?highlight=cmake_user_make_rules_override

So what you can then do is change the value by doing something like this from within this override file:

```
string(REPLACE "-O3" "-O2" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT })
```

I've never heard of these variables before so I'm not entirely sure how they work regarding path locations when setting `CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE_<lang>`.

I suspect that you can set `CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE_<lang>` from within the toolchain file instead of the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: Today, I tried to use it. It did not work. Neither in toolchain, nor before project. I guess the optimization is set after the overrides are loaded.